# When I download a text file in safari the results are displayed in the browser not sent to a file

Tags: windows-7, macos, download, safari

When I download a text file in safari the results show up in the browser.  In Chrome and FireFox the results are sent directly to a file on my computer.  Is there a way to make Safari do that same thing by default?  I can see the file name in the url but the results just display in the browser.

The link to the file is a button action, so when you click on the download button the file downloads.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no setting that you can change to enable this, however there are two ways you can do it that simply requires an extra keyboard command or mouse click.

- Alt+Click on the text file will allow you to download it instead of open the link
- Right clicking on the link will give you the option to 'Download linked file as'

Answer (score 0):

DISCALIMER : I NEVER USED SAFARI

This is available on many browsers so I ASSUME that it is available in Safari too :

- Right click on the link to the file and select `Save as...`
- Browse to where you want to download the file

Comment: This explains how to download files, but doesn't address the OP's issue with regards to getting .txt files to download instead of open in the browser.

Comment: @Diago : I've updated my answer. You may want to remove your downvote after reviewing it.